# How to convert portrait to landscape video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using FFmpeg and I'm aware that it is the fastest offline video and audio converter. Suddenly I've tried to convert portrait videos into landscape but upon checking its Outcome, it changes its aspect ratio and the video become chubby and that is what I don't like at all. I want to convert portrait videos into landscape video that maintains the aspect ratio and its orientation as portrait.

Comment: Please post the command that you've used

Comment: ffmpeg -y -i "/storage/0040-18A0/FFMPEG/input.mp4" -s 720x480 -target ntsc-dvd -ps 1000000000 -aspect 4:3 "/storage/0040-18A0/FFMPEG/output.mpeg"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly I think that you need to pillarbox your video.
It will upscale it and add vertical black bars (pillars).

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "scale=1280:720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1280:720:-1:-1:color=black" output.mp4`

Comment: Okay, let me try this one and see the outcome. Can i change your given resolution to whatever i want?

Comment: [swscaler @ 04cdb4e0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[Parsed_pad_1 @ 046be4e0] Negative values are not acceptable.
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 046be560] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_pad_1
Error opening filters!